# Nginx: Serve PHP files from defined location only

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, static-files

I have an AngularJS app in `/home/app/front` and a PHP backend in `/home/app/back`. Now I would like to serve static files from `/` and PHP from `/api/v1/`

I tried the following config with no success. Nginx throws the following error message: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"`

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/wpplugins/frontend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ^~ /api/v1/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/wpplugins/backend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_index /index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The regex indicator looks off, try `location ~* ^/api/v1/ {`

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Try commenting out the `fastcgi_index` line.

Comment: Still same problem